# Approximation Class that Decides

Tags: complexity-theory, approximation, complexity-classes

Suppose we have a minimization ILP. Denote its value by $OPT$.
Let $PER$ be the solution to its LP relaxation.
Given a real number $t$, we would like to decide whether $OPT \leq (1+t) \cdot PER$, in time polynomial in the problem size and $1/t$.

Denote by FPTAD, the class of ILPs for which this is doable in polynomial time.
Of course, P is contained in FPTAD.
But, we proved that some ILP are in FPTAD, but not in P (unless P=NP).
We can also prove that, if a problem is in FPTAD, then it has an FPTAS using binary search.

Is the opposite (if a problem has an FPTAS then it is in FPTAD), also true?

Comment: $P$ is a set of decision problems (languages). FPTAD is a set of integer linear programs. What does it mean that P is contained in FPTAD?

Comment: From wikipedia: The term FPTAS may also be used to refer to the class of problems that have an FPTAS. It is the same for FPTAD.

Comment: But the problem that have an FPTAS are optimization problems, not decision problems...

Comment: What is the problem with decision problems? It still can define a class of problems.